# No recorre mi bucle while en mi consulta PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Mi bucle **while** esta solo recorriendo una vez `json_encode($resultado->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))` y no toda la base de datos.

Necesito que recorra y muestre toda la tabla de mi base de datos.

Este es mi código:

```
<?php

include '../bd/global.php';

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET'){
    if(isset($_GET['documento'])){
        $query="select * from creditos where documento=".$_GET['documento'];
        $resultado=metodoGet($query);
       
        while($recorrer=$resultado->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
        {
          echo json_encode($resultado->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
                    
            
        }
    }else{
        $query="select * from creditos where aprobado != 'Credito aprobado y sin procesar'";
        $resultado=metodoGet($query);
        echo json_encode($resultado->fetchAll()); 
    }
    header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
    exit();
}

header("HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request");
?>
```

Comment: En primer lugar no digas que *recorre toda tu base de datos*, lo que en realidad se recorre es el resultado de la consulta

Comment: si señor, me puedes ayudar?

Comment: lastimosamente nop :(, no he trabajado con PDO.

Comment: gracias quedo pendiente..

Comment: ¿Necesitas que cada fila por cada iteración se convierta en un *json*?

Comment: si,  es lo que necesito

Comment: el problema es el output... envias una salida con los echo´s cuando deberias de almacenarlos y mostrarlos una sola vez....

Comment: Y el método `metodoGet` que hace y como regresa los resultados?

Answer (score 0):

El principal problema está en la lógica del recorrido `while`. Recordar que cada vez que se llama la instrucción `fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)`, se mueve el apuntador de la fila al siguiente registro.

Supongamos que tenemos los siguientes datos de ejemplo:

```
id | data
---+-----
1  | one
2  | two
3  | three
4  | four
```

Si aplicamos la lógica del código de la pregunta, solo se mostrarán los resultados de 2 en 2.

```
while($recorrer=$resultado->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { // Mueve el puntero
    echo json_encode($resultado->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)); // Mueve el puntero
}
```

El resultado será:

```
{"id":"2", "data":"two"}
{"id":"4", "data":"four"}
```

---

Si solo quieres recorrer el objeto PDO, fila por fila, entonces utiliza la variable `$recorrer` declarada en el `while`:

```
while($recorrer=$resultado->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { 
    echo json_encode($recorrer);
}
```

O bien, puedes convertir el objeto PDO completo en Array con `fetchAll`:

```
$all_data = $resultado->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$json_data = json_encode($all_data);
echo $json_data;
```

Resultado:

```
[
    {"id":"1", "data":"one"},
    {"id":"2", "data":"two"},
    {"id":"3", "data":"three"},
    {"id":"4", "data":"four"}
]
```

Comment: al realizar la prueba solo me carga una fila sea con cualquier de las dos opciones que me envio ,  so quieres puedes probar en postman https://www.creditos.hoztcreative.com/apiCreditos/paginacion/index.php?documento=1110498191  // deberia aparecer dos filas pero solo aparece una

Comment: gracias ya puede solucionar con las opciones que me envio...